# How can I check ng-if value with one php value

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

How can I check ng-if value with one php value.Is this possible..?
Give me some solution....

```
<div ng-if="val.PRDCODE=='<?=$value?>'">
</div>
```

Comment: what is your nf-if condition suppose to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not a good way of doing that. If you want to do, then simply fire an AJAX call and set your `value` in controller scope's object. But if you want to do it in this way then you can achieve it by using `ng-init` directive, like I've done in one of my projects. Just use

```
<div data-ng-app="MyApp" data-ng-controller="DemoController" data-ng-init="value='<?php echo $value?>'">
```

and in your condition, use like

```
<div data-ng-if="val.PRDCODE == value">
```

Hope it may help you.

Comment: My pleasure to help you.

Comment: ng-init=" value='<?php echo $value?>' , value_new='<?php echo $value_new?>' "  is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you have problems in getting values on the webpage. You can simple call a function and return true/false which can be evaluated on the page.

e.g

```
<div ng-if="myCondition()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a great approach and also has a risk to expose your private data in the source code. But If you dont care about your data to be exposed then you can;

```
<head>
<script>
    angular.module("NAME OF YOUR APP")
    .controller("name___ctrl", function($scope){
    $scope.phpValue = '<?php $value; ?>'
    });
</script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="name___ctrl">
 {{phpValue}}
</body>
```

**Another way is to use ng-init**

```
<div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
  <span ng-init="phpValue= true">something</span>
</div>
```

**This would be the healthiest overall..**

An Angular way of getting data in, is to use services/factories. Basically make an http call to a json responding endpoint and fetch the data.

//Make sure to make your $http calls inside your Factories or Services. This is just for a testing purpose.

```
.controller(function($http){
 $http.get("api/endpoint")
.then(function(success)
    {
       phpValue = success.data
    },
    function(error)
    {
        console.log("oops something went really wrong")
    })
})
```

once you got phpdata just use it as you wish

```
<div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
  <span ng-if="someValue == phpValue">something</span>
</div>
```